# Python - GigaTools API - json

Tags: python, json

I would like to retrieve data from the GigaTools API via a JSON call using Python. There is no detailed API documentation, but some general instructions can be found here on [GigaTools](http://api.gigatools.com).

Suppose, I would like to find all Gigs for Twitter user:

https://twitter.com/DJFlash4eva

According to the documentation, I would need to make the following API call:

> /search.json?api_key=XXXXXXXX&twitter_username=djflash4eva

Given that there is no specific python wrapper for the GigaTools API, how could such a request be implemented? A short example code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are loads of posts here already about using HTTP libraries to retrieve JSON from a URL and decoding it. Did you try any of that yet?

Comment: Using the external `requests` library for example would simply be `requests.get(url, params={'api_key': 'XXXX', 'twitter_username': 'djflash4eva'}).json()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the requests module

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get("http://api.gigatools.com/search.json", params={'api_key': 'XXXX', 'twitter_username': 'djflash4eva'})
>>> print(response.status_code)
>>> print(response.text)
```

source: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/